# Use one instance of class in multiple Fragments

Tags: java, android-fragments, interface

What is the best way to use one instance of a Class in multiple Fragments? (or just a method of it)

In my Application I have a Class `RangeFetcher` which downloads an XML-file and parses it into a model class `Item`. `RangeFetcher` holds an `ArrayList<Item> items` containing the whole XML-file parsed into instances of the model.

I'm creating the Fragment `ShopFragment` from my starting activity `ShopMainViewScreen`. In this Fragment I instantiate a `RangeFetcher`. Since this is a pretty expensive operation in terms of data volume and computing, I would like to pass this instance of `RangeFetcher` to the other three Fragments I have.

This method **getItems** is basically all I need in the fragments.

```
public class RangeFetcher extends AsyncTask {

  ArrayList <Item> items = new ArrayList();

  //filling the List...

  public ArrayList <Item> getItems() {
    return items;
  }
}
```

What i took into consideration up to now:

- I thought about using a bundle and passing the ArrayList in the arguments to pass the instance from one Fragment to another, but that feels kinda clunky. Could this cause trouble regarding the back-stack?
- making the method `getItems` static? I think it would be feasible since the `RangeFetcher` will always produce exactly the same output for all the fragments. (am I missing something here?)
- Do you have any other suggestions on how to access this instance from multiple fragments?

**`RangeFetcher` Class**

```js
    package com.XXX;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    //I know using a switch statement would probably be more fitting here.
    //Furthermore I didn't know how to wait for the background task to
    //finish so i just introduced a boolean "processing". When this boolean
    //is set to false, i continue with my tasks on the fragments.
    //So feel free to suggest some improvements to my code ^^
    public class RangeFetcher extends AsyncTask {

     URL url;
     ArrayList < Item > items = new ArrayList();
     boolean processing = false;
     Item i;

     protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
      processing = true;

      try {
       url = new URL("XXXX");

       XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
       factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
       XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

       xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");


       boolean insideItem = false;
       boolean priceSet = false;

       int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
       while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

         if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
          insideItem = true;
          i = new Item();

         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:id")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmID(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmTitle(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmDescription(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:product_type")) {
          if (insideItem) {
           String fullCategory = xpp.nextText();
           if (fullCategory.contains(" ")) {
            fullCategory = fullCategory.substring(0, fullCategory.indexOf(" "));
           }
           i.setmProductType(fullCategory);
          }
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:image_link")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmPictureLink(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:condition")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmCondition(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:availability")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmAvailability(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:price") && priceSet == false) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmPrice(xpp.nextText());
          priceSet = true;
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:brand")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmBrand(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:mpn")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmMpn(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:country")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmShippingCountry(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:service")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmService(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:price")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setmShippingCosts(xpp.nextText());
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:pubDate")) {
          if (insideItem)
           i.setMpubDate(xpp.nextText());
         }

        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
         insideItem = false;
         items.add(i);
         priceSet = false;
        }
        eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
       }
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      processing = false;
      return items;
     }

     private InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
      try {
       return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       return null;
      }
     }

     public ArrayList < Item > getItems() {
      while (processing == true) {}
      return items;
     }

     public Boolean processing() {
      return processing;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Read about Singleton pattern

Comment: @Mershel thank you. 9 lines of code just sped up my application by approximately 300% ^^